# In a high pressure water pump what component or design parameter increases pressure output, let's say from 200 atm o 2000 atm?

Tags: design, pressure, pumps

type of flow? length or diameter of the plunger piston?, or weight of the piston and crankshaft and torque or HP to move it?, or RPM. direct drive pumps used in waterjet cutting use a slim plunger instead the thick plunger of triplex pumps for pressure washing

Comment: at is all of the above. Amount of compression is going to be based on physical properties of size & speed; then the power required & rpm to make it go is an output spec form the mechanical design.  Crankshaft/piston specs will also be based on the stresses on them according to the design.

Comment: what research have you done? IIRC the wikipedia article on water cutting explains it nicely